# ValidationGroup on Fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a `FormView` where there is a `FileUpload` with a `RequiredFieldValidator` and I need to have a `validationGroup` on the `FileUpload` or else my `Button` won't go it's `PostBackUrl`.

My code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="fwResultsInsert" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ResultsID" 
            DataSourceID="ObjResults" DefaultMode="Insert">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblImagess" runat="server" Text="Resultat Billede:"></asp:Label>

        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuResultsImages" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvImage" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Her mangler noget!!" ControlToValidate="fuResultsImages"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Error" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPicture" runat="server" Visible="True" />
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnInsert" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Insert" Text="Insæt" onclick="btnInsert_Click" ForeColor="#000000" Font-Underline="True" />
                &nbsp; <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" 
                    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Fortryd" ForeColor="#000000" Font-Underline="True" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>

<asp:Button ID="btnHome" runat="server" Text="Forsiden" PostBackUrl="~/BackEnd/Default.aspx" />
```

I need to have some kind of validation on my `FileUpload`, so there have to be something in the fileupload-box when I clink insert, atm I have a `RequiredFieldValidator`, but there is a conflict with another `Button` I have outside the `FormView`, atm when I click the button nothing happens unless there is something in the `FileUpload`, and that's not the point.

Comment: Sorry, I really have no idea what your question is. Please give a better description of exactly what you need to happen, and what is currently happening that shouldn't be happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `CausesValidation="false"` to the `Button` which you have outside the `FormView`.

Ex:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnHome" runat="server" Text="Forsiden" PostBackUrl="~/BackEnd/Default.aspx" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnHome_Click" />
```